# Twitter API retrieve tweets with search_query for time range (more than year past)

Tags: api, twitter, tweepy

Is there a way to collect tweets that match specific keyword, but are more than year old date range? I know you can collect tweet with search query on stream api, but I would like to grab tweets that are more than 1 year old, and also would like to specify the date range.

Answer (score 1):

From [the Twitter Search Documentation](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/search/overview).

> The Twitter Search API searches against a sampling of recent Tweets published in the past 7 days.

So, you can't grab historic data via the API.

You *can* specify date ranges using `until:2015-12-21` as part of your query.

Comment: since is no longer a parameter